# window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {} ) doesn't record when I drag and drop a piece of text

Tags: typescript, addeventlistener

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body id="main-body">
    <script src="index.js"></script>

    <p id="para">This is a paragraph</p>

</body>

</html>
```

index.ts

```
const body = document.getElementById('main-body')

let posX: number, posY: number;
let mouseDownX: number, mouseDownY: number;
let clicked: boolean = false;


window.addEventListener('mousedown', e =>{
  if(!clicked){
    mouseDownX = e.clientX;
    mouseDownY = e.clientY;
    clicked = true;
  }  
  console.log('Mouse clicked');
})


window.addEventListener('mousemove', e =>{
  if(!clicked) {
    mouseDownX = e.clientX;
    mouseDownY = e.clientY;
  }
  const deltaDX = mouseDownX - e.clientX,
        deltaDY = mouseDownY - e.clientY,
        maxDelta = window.innerWidth/2;
  const percentageX = Math.abs(deltaDX/maxDelta);
  const percentageY = Math.abs(deltaDY/maxDelta);

  body?.style.setProperty('background-color', `rgb(0, ${255*percentageX}, ${255*percentageY})`)
})

window.addEventListener('mouseup', () =>{
  clicked = false;
})
```

I've made a simple script that changes the background color based on how far I click and drag the mouse In the index.ts, I used the window.addEventListener('mouseup') to keep track of when I stopped dragging. It worked just fine when I clicked and dragged in an empty space, as soon as I selected a piece of text from "This is a paragraph" and dragged when I dropped it, it didn't register as a mouseup event and the script just stopped working as I intended

I don't even know where to start fixing this problem and I don't yet have the knowledge to do some research on this problem
How do I fix this?

Comment: *" and the script just broke"* --  What error did it give you?

Comment: @Zak well broke is a strong word but the script stopped working as I intended. It's changing color even if I just move my mouse and don't click

Comment: In order to duplicate the issue without having to create a project, I created [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13qdvb74/) --  So it appears your issue is with SELECTING text and THEN trying to drag it?

Comment: @Zak yes. When I drop the text (mouse up), the clicked variable doesn't change to false as it should be. I don't know how jsfiddle works but it didn't duplicate the issue, did it?

Comment: @Zak oh my bad, you console.logged out the rgb value. Yea that is the exact issue